# Question about bool in C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering why the code below only returns "Test" four times, instead of five?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cassert>
    using namespace std;

    class CountDown
    {
      public: //Application Programmer Interface
        CountDown(int start); // it is set to start
        void next(); // subtracts one from it
        bool end()const; //
     private:
        int it;
    };

    CountDown::CountDown(int start)
    {
        it = 0;
        it = start;
    }

    void CountDown::next()
    {
        it = it - 1;
    }

    bool CountDown::end() const
    {
        if (it <= 0)
          cout << "The countdown is now over" << endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        for( CountDown i = 5 ; ! i.end(); i.next())
        std::cerr << "test\n";
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing a `return` from your `end` method?

Comment: can you post correct definition of `end` method.

Comment: I am a little bit confused as well, the statement 'CountDown i = 5' should not be working. Shouldn't it be 'CountDown* i = new CountDown(5)' or just 'CountDown i(5)'

Comment: @Robert: `CountDown i = 5` is valid; the non-explicit constructor allows implicit conversion from an integer. If the constructor were explicit, then it would have to be `CountDown i(5)` as you say. You shouldn't use `new` when automatic storage will work, especially in a case like this where there's no sensible way to delete the object after use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point in doing this double initialization:

```
CountDown::CountDown(int start)
{
    it = 0;
    it = start;
}
```

This is enough:

```
CountDown::CountDown(int start)
{
    it = start;
}
```

Or even this, using the initialization list:

```
CountDown::CountDown(int start):it(start)
{
}
```

As for end() you don't return any value from it. The method should probably look like this:

```
bool CountDown::end() const
{
    return it <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
bool CountDown::end() const
  {
   if (it > 1) return false;
   return true;
  }
```

Comment: Unnecessary obfuscation: `it > 1` has type `bool`, and can be output directly (or negated, but I'd rather inverse the test: `it <= 0`).  Of course, the value is wrong anyway: as you've written it, it should be `it > 0`.